# Rails better_errors gem alternative gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'g getting always on exception: "Session expired >>> undefined" in better_errors gem.
[image]
I find out that it may cause by using multi worker server, but I'm using single worker in development mode.

Can anyone help to solve this issue **OR** **advice alternative gem**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to debug in steps you can try either of this gem:

1. [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) for better formatting in Rails console and use `binding.pry` to the breakpoints.
2. [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) which is included out of the box in Rails 4.x, just drop `byebug` to the breakpoints.

Alternatively you can use [web console](https://github.com/rails/web-console) gem that allows your Rails app to show up Rails console in the webpage itself.